# How to connect neo 6m 6pin module with nodemcu v3

Tags: nodemcu, gps, wires

I got this neo 6m gps module from a broken drone. and i would like to connect it to nodemcu v3 board.
most of the gps module that i have seen are with 4 pins (vcc,gnd,tx,rx) , but this module has 6 pins (gnd,vcc,txd,rxd,scl,sda) .

i am not sure how to wire it up and what library to use.

[image: Neo 6]
[image: NodeMcu v3]

Comment: Have you read the datasheet for the NEO M6?

Comment: @MatsK  i am a just beginner, don't understand much about diagram.

Comment: Ok, then just hook up 3 wires like this: GND - GND, Tx - Rx, Rx - Tx. And then start to read this: https://lastminuteengineers.com/neo6m-gps-arduino-tutorial/  NB The NodeMCU is a 3,3 volt device and the url is using a std Arduino, a 5 volt device, please adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4 pins VCC/GND/TX/RX are the same as any other GPS module.

The other two pins, SCL and SDA, are nothing to do with the GPS. They connect to the HMC5883L compass chip.

Use the normal TinyGPS library for the GPS, and a HMC5883L library (such as [this one](https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-HMC5883L)) for the compass.

Answer (score 0):

Rx and tx pin are for UART communication and SCL and SDA are for I2C communication. Most common gps module use UART communication method .... You can go with UART too this will help you to choose better  library option. Most library file are coded for UART method.  I recommend you to use vcc , gnd ,rx and tx pin. Escape scl and sda pins.

Comment: The I2C is not connected to the GPS. It's only connected to the HMC5883L.

Comment: I have just cleared about communication protocol ...not suggested to use i2c communication 